# h:dataTable Nested Sorting Issue

Tags: sorting, jsf

I have a sorting issue in a JSF `h:dataTable`.

I have to structure a table where the initial overall-sorting-criterion is a score-number in the first column.

If there are multiple entries with the same score, then those entries shall be sorted in function of a second column with names, which shall appear in alphabetical order.

If again there should be multiple entries with the same values in the first and second column, then those entries shall be sorted in function of a third column, which is a location name, which shall be listed again in alphabetical order.

If again there should be multiple entries with the same values in the first, second, and third column, then those entries shall be sorted in function of a fourth column, which is an age-number, which shall appear in ascending order.

I know that I can achieve the initial-sorting score-number with the "sortBy" attribute and sortingOrder=ascending. But I struggle with the other before mentioned sorting-requirements, which is where I am looking for help...Is there a way of doing this without having to use custom sort functions?

Here is the xhtml-code of the dataTable.

```
            <h:dataTable value = "#{userData.employees}" 
              var = "employee"
              styleClass = "employeeTable"
              headerClass = "employeeTableHeader"
              rowClasses = "employeeTableOddRow,employeeTableEvenRow"
              sortBy=“#{employee.score}“ sortOrder=“ascending“>
             <h:column>
              <f:facet id = "header">score</f:facet>
                #{employee.score}
             </h:column>

             <h:column>                 
              <f:facet name = "header">Name</f:facet>                   
               #{employee.name}
             </h:column>

             <h:column>
              <f:facet name = "header">Location</f:facet>
              #{employee.location }
             </h:column>

             <h:column>
              <f:facet name = "header">Age</f:facet>
              #{employee.age}
             </h:column>
           </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: You can do this by actually using the primefaces DataTable with `sortMode="multiple"` and `sortBy="#{userData.employeeSortingMeta}"` returning a List of `org.primefaces.model.SortMeta` instances.

First of all you'll have to convert your plain HTML JSF dataTable to a Primefaces Datatable, adding ID attributes to dataTable and columns plus adding sortBy attributes to each column:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
           ...
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form id="frmEmployees">
<p:dataTable id="tblEmployees" value = "#{userData.employees}" 
  var = "employee"
  styleClass = "employeeTable"
  headerClass = "employeeTableHeader"
  rowClasses = "employeeTableOddRow,employeeTableEvenRow"
  sortBy=“#{userData.employeeSortingMeta}“ sortMode=“multiple“>
 <p:column id="score" sortBy="#{employee.score}">
  <f:facet id = "header">score</f:facet>
    #{employee.score}
 </p:column>

 <p:column id="name" sortBy="#{employee.name}">                 
  <f:facet name = "header">Name</f:facet>                   
   #{employee.name}
 </p:column>

 <p:column id="location" sortBy="#{employee.location}">
  <f:facet name = "header">Location</f:facet>
  #{employee.location }
 </p:column>

 <p:column id="age" sortBy="#{employee.age}">
  <f:facet name = "header">Age</f:facet>
  #{employee.age}
 </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

In your bean, create methods to build the sorting meta data:

```
private List<SortMeta> employeeSortingMeta;

public List<SortMeta> getEmployeeSortingMeta() {
    return this.employeeSortingMeta;
}

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    employeeSortingMeta = new ArrayList<>(4);
    employeeSortingMeta.add(createSortMeta("score", SortOrder.DESCENDING));
    employeeSortingMeta.add(createSortMeta("name", SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    employeeSortingMeta.add(createSortMeta("location", SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    employeeSortingMeta.add(createSortMeta("age", SortOrder.ASCENDING));
}

private SortMeta createSortMeta(final String sortProperty, final SortOrder order) {
    // find the sort column component
    final UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    final String columnIdPrefix = "frmEmployees:tblEmployees:";
    final UIColumn column = (UIColumn) viewRoot.findComponent(columnIdPrefix + sortProperty);
    assert null != column : "wtf?";

    // create sort meta
    final SortMeta sortMeta = new SortMeta();
    sortMeta.setSortBy(column);
    sortMeta.setSortField(sortProperty);
    sortMeta.setSortOrder(order);
    return sortMeta;
}
```

That should be it.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt, detailed answer. After several rounds of testing, we can confirm that it definitely did the job!